# Getting strings, variables from txt file, and using in Main script

Tags: python

I've recently started learning Python.
Here I have a simple Register/Login System which performs and saves the data into the TXT File. So after this "Save" system which I'm using with f.write() Function, how could I get the saved files, as passwords, money, gmail address? After putting variable of a Ballance = 500.00 to new account, in Register function, I do get errors of more future scripts, is that many variables, strings are not defined. So how could i "extract or get" the strings and variables from TXT File, and use in main script?
MY code of Register/Login, you could also say, if there are any problems inside the code.

```
global username1, password2, ballance, username2, password2
check = True
Login_Register = input("Welcome,\nType L for Login, R to Register\n")
if Login_Register == "l" or Login_Register =="L":
    while check:
        with open(ban_list, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            username1 = input("Enter your username: ")
            password1 = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
            for line in f:
                if("Username:"+username1+" Password:"+password1) == line.strip():
                    print("you are logged in")
                    check = False
                    break;
                else:
                    check = False
                    print("Username or password does not exist")
                    continue

elif "r" in Login_Register or "R" in Login_Register:
 while True:
     try:
            ballance = 500.00
            f = open(ban_list, mode='a+')
            username2 = input("~ Please enter your Username!\n")
            password2 = getpass.getpass("~ Please enter your password!\n")
            Gmail = input("~ Please add your Email address!\n")
            f.write(f"\nUsername:{username2} Password:{password2} Gmail:{Gmail} Ballance:{ballance}\n")
            f.close()
            print("username and password has been made")

            break;
     except ValueError:
        print('* Not a value !')

print("WElcome {} ".format(username1))
```

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you want done please

Comment: I would like to ask why is there two of username(1,2) also the password(1,2), If I want to use them in other function, I do get an error, that the username1,2 is not defined. How could i get any detail from the text file, which i use like database. Or there are any better ways to put this data on database?

Comment: So when you put username(1,2) and password(1,2) into a function you get an error saying that they are not defined?

Comment: Yes, for example in other function like while True: print("Welcome {}, your password {}, register date {}, ballance {}".format(username,password,regdate,ballance)) I would like to make it to look something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new code:

```
global username1, password2, ballance, username2, password2
check = True
Login_Register = input("Welcome,\nType L for Login, R to Register\n")
if Login_Register == "l" or Login_Register =="L":
    while check:
        with open('accountfile.txt','r') as f:
            username1 = input("Enter your username: ")
            password1 = input("Enter your password: ")
            for line in f:
                text = line.strip().split()
                if username1 == text[1] and password1 == text[3]:
                    print("you are logged in")
                    check = False
                    print("Welcome", username1)
                    break;
                else:
                    print("Username or password does not exist")
                    break;

elif "r" == Login_Register or "R" == Login_Register:
    ballance = 500.00
    f = open('accountfile.txt','a+')
    username2 = input("~ Please enter your Username!\n")
    password2 = input("~ Please enter your password!\n")
    Gmail = input("~ Please add your Email address!\n")
    f.write(f"\nUsername: {username2} Password: {password2} Gmail: {Gmail} Ballance: {ballance}\n")
    f.close()
    print("username and password has been made")
```

Comment: Could I just load data from the TXT file, and just use the ballance, username, password everywhere?

Comment: @JamesSmith yes every time you make a new function just copy what I did

Comment: I think it does, but the def, seems not nice. Is there any way just to make these variables global, with no def?

Comment: @JamesSmith just put them at the top of your code don't need def

Comment: I'll add my code in the post code section, you can check the errors if you can on your own editor. When i run terminal it says like 10x times if the user login combination did not succeed. Another error is about register, it writes the lines to TXT File, but when I try to login it says that this user does not exist.

Comment: @JamesSmith ok I will try my best to fix it

Comment: I think i need, to have one global string like password, username. To use it everywhere, cause of these two they're causing me problems

Comment: @JamesSmith I edited my answer above, it has the new code

Comment: Thanks for your advice to fix it, and your help. I edited my code myself, I  fixed it, I wont test it, but if it does work, then it should be good for others who'l get this type of question.

Comment: But I advice to use classes, that's the better way to edit them.

Comment: @JamesSmith yes I saw your other question it is better